# Conditional statements in Spring Controller questions

Tags: java, spring, security, controller, conditional-statements

So a have a blueprint code of a web app which allows different accounts with logins to upload simple files. However, there are security flaws that allow non-admin accounts to enter database configurations and direct object referencing (download files of other accounts by URL tampering). I was recommended a solution whereby I check if the owner of the uploaded file is the same one trying to download it. But doing that in a spring @controller posed a few problems. If you look at my get statement to get a specific file, you see that I got the file object and the account object. Then I just check if the name is the same of file owner. But how do I "return" something in a controller while in an "if" statement?

```
@Controller
public class FileController {

    @Autowired
    private FileRepository fileRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/files", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(Authentication authentication, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("files", accountRepository.findByUsername(authentication.getName()).getFileObjects());
        return "files";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/files/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> viewFile(@PathVariable Long id) {
        //1. get object or name account name
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();
        //2. check if the file account is of the same name
        FileObject fo = fileRepository.findOne(id);
        if((fo.getAccount().getUsername()).equals(currentPrincipalName)) {

            System.out.println("WHAT AM I SUPPOSED TO DO!?");


        }



        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(fo.getContentType()));
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fo.getName());
        headers.setContentLength(fo.getContentLength());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(fo.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/files", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addFile(Authentication authentication, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        Account account = accountRepository.findByUsername(authentication.getName());


        FileObject fileObject = new FileObject();
        fileObject.setContentType(file.getContentType());
        fileObject.setContent(file.getBytes());
        fileObject.setName(file.getOriginalFilename());
        fileObject.setContentLength(file.getSize());
        fileObject.setAccount(account);

        fileRepository.save(fileObject);


        return "redirect:/files";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/files/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        fileRepository.delete(id);
        return "redirect:/files";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you're supposed to put the code that follows the if block **inside** the if block. So that you only send the file content if the account is the right one. Why do you return a status CREATED from a GET? You didn't create anything. OK is the appropriate status.

Comment: It's a boilerplate code that I got. It's working so I don't mess with that part. What I do have to mess with is the security :/

Comment: What about throwing an `AccessDeniedException` of some sort?

Comment: That's an interesting idea! @MartinFrey